# LAN connection not working in network with two routers (WiFi works)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I have added a new Wireless router to my home network, because I was not satisfied with the coverage of the old one, but I still have to keep the old one, because it serves also as a modem. On the picture you can see my current setup.

[image: Network]

I think that I have configured everything correctly, but for some reason the connection is only working Wirelessly, but not via LAN.

On WiFi devices, I can access both routers via their IP addresses and I can access the Internet without any problem.

On LAN, I'm not able to access the Internet, moreover I'm not even able to access any of the routers.
When checking `ipconfig` of the Desktop PC, I can see the following, so there's definitely something wrong:

```
Autoconfiguration IPV4 Address..: 169.254.11.25 (Preferred)
Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway.................: (empty)
```

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two LANs now, one for each router. LAN 1 (between router 1 and router 2) has no DHCP server, so devices won't be automatically assigned IP and DNS addresses.

1. If you only want to extend WiFi coverage, return router 2 and buy an access point instead. SOHO "routers" aren't actually just routers, but router+switch+access point combos (+ modem in your case). You don't want any extra routing in your setup.
2. If that's not an option, re-enable DHCP on router 1, then disable DHCP on router 2 and reconfigure it into bridge mode. Bridge mode will effectively disable the router part, leaving just switch and AP.
3. Finally, you can just enable DHCP on router 1. This should get everything working, although such configuration comes with its share of problems:

   - Devices from LAN 1 can't talk to devices in LAN 2 unless the device in LAN 2 initiates the communication. That's because LAN 2 is behind a NAT. I guess you could work around this by setting appropriate static routes if your router(s) allow this.
   - Devices in LAN 2 are behind double NAT, so to host a server there you have to manually forward ports on router 1 (in addition to router 2, which will either also require manual port forwarding or may be autoconfigured with UPnP).

You can have WiFi enabled on both routers, btw. If the network name and password are identical, your devices will automatically switch between APs to get best connection quality.

Comment: Thank you for for answer and providing several possible solution. At the end I have turned on DHCP back on the Router 1 and I'm using Router 2 in AP mode. Everything works now well.

Answer (score 1):

Who is delivering DHCP to the ethernet switch and everything connected to that?
No one, because router 1 is the only one that can do that and you disabled DHCP there.
And that is why the computer gets a self-generated ip-address, which is useless.

The rest of the setup is OK.

Only thing is that you have a double NAT going on for devices behind router 2. That may give complications if you need port-forwarding.

Comment: Thank you for first answer. You were right with the cause of the issue. I haven't realized this.